# How to print cards side by side

Tags: python, blackjack

HERE IS MY CODE BELOW.
Ive tried multiple different things and asked in discord servers but no one has been able to respond or help me.

```
#import modules
import random
import os
import time

#global variables
random_suit = ['♠','♥','♦','♣']
random_card = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
lettered_card = ['A', 'J', 'Q', 'K']

dealer_sum = 0
user_sum = 0

dealer_cards = []
dealer_suit = []

turns = 0

user_cards = []
user_suit = []

user_balance = og_balance = 1000.00
user_bet = 0


# Print cards
def card_print(chosen_suit,chosen_card):
    print(f'*------*')
    print(f'| {chosen_card:<2}   |')
    print(f'|      |')
    print(f'|    {chosen_suit} |')
    print(f'*------*')


#run
def main():
    os.system('cls')
    print('----------------------')
    print('Welcome to Blackjack!')
    bets()
    user_hand(2)
    time.sleep(1)
    dealer_hand()
    time.sleep(1)
    check_sum()
    hit_stay()

#bets
def bets():
    global user_bet
    global user_balance
    print(f'Your balance is currently: ${user_balance}')
    bet = int(input('How much would you like to bet?: $'))
    if bet < 0 or bet < 10:
        print('Minimum bet is $10')
        time.sleep(1)
        main()
    if bet > user_balance:
        print('Not enough money in balance')
        time.sleep(1)
        main()
    elif bet < user_balance:
        user_bet += bet
    else:
        print('Invalid Session.')
        time.sleep(1)
        main()

# Print dealer hand
def dealer_hand():
    global dealer_sum
    print('-------------')
    print('Dealer Hand: ')
    time.sleep(1)
    chosen_card = random.choice(random_card)
    chosen_suit = random.choice(random_suit)

    dealer_cards.append(str(chosen_card))
    dealer_suit.append(str(chosen_suit))

    dealer_sum += check_letters(chosen_card)
    card_print(chosen_suit,chosen_card)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f'*------*')
    print(f'| ???? |')
    print(f'| ???? |')
    print(f'| ???? |')
    print(f'*------*')
    print('Dealer Total: ', dealer_sum)

# Print user hand
def user_hand(amount):
    global user_sum
    print('-------------')
    print('Your Hand: ')
    for i in range(amount):
        time.sleep(1)
        chosen_card = random.choice(random_card)
        chosen_suit = random.choice(random_suit)

        user_cards.append(str(chosen_card))
        user_suit.append(str(chosen_suit))

        user_sum += check_letters(chosen_card)
        card_print(chosen_suit, chosen_card)
    print('Your Total: ', user_sum)

# Convert letters to numbers
def check_letters(chosen_card):
    if chosen_card.isdigit():
        return int(chosen_card)
    else:
        for _ in lettered_card:
            if chosen_card != 'A':
                return 10
            else:
                return 11

# Check if the total of the dealer or user is over 21
def check_sum():
    global user_bet
    global user_balance
    def win(bj):
        global user_bet
        global user_balance
        if bj:
            user_bet_won = user_bet * 1.75
            user_balance += user_bet_won
        else:
            user_bet_won = user_bet * 1.25
            user_balance += user_bet_won

    def lose():
        global user_bet
        global user_balance
        user_bet_lost = user_bet * 1.25
        user_balance -= user_bet_lost

    if user_sum > 21:
        print('-------------')
        print('Your over 21! You lose!')
        lose()
        play_again()
    elif dealer_sum > 21:
        print('-------------')
        print('Dealer over 21! You win!')
        win(False)
        play_again()
    elif user_sum == 21:
        print('-------------')
        print('You have Blackjack. You win!')
        win(True)
        play_again()
    elif dealer_sum == 21:
        print('-------------')
        print('Dealer has blackjack. You lose!')
        lose()
        play_again()
    elif dealer_sum > user_sum and turns > 0:
        print('-------------')
        print('Dealer has more. You lose!')
        lose()
        play_again()
    else:
        pass

# Hit or Knock
def hit_stay():
    global turns
    turns += 1
    def hit():
        global user_sum
        global dealer_sum
        os.system('cls')
        print('-------------')
        print('HIT')
        #print('P Cards:', user_cards, user_suit)
        #print('D Cards:', dealer_cards, dealer_suit)

        #your hand
        print('-------------')
        print('Your Hand: ')
        for i_index, card in enumerate(user_cards):
            card_print(user_suit[i_index], card)

        time.sleep(1)
        chosen_card = random.choice(random_card)
        chosen_suit = random.choice(random_suit)

        user_cards.append(str(chosen_card))
        user_suit.append(str(chosen_suit))

        user_sum += check_letters(chosen_card)
        card_print(chosen_suit, chosen_card)
        print('Your Total: ', user_sum)

        # dealer hand
        print('-------------')
        print('Dealer Hand: ')
        for i_index, card in enumerate(dealer_cards):
            card_print(dealer_suit[i_index], card)

        if dealer_sum >= 17:
            check_sum()
            hit_stay()
        elif dealer_sum < 17:
            time.sleep(1)
            chosen_card = random.choice(random_card)
            chosen_suit = random.choice(random_suit)

            dealer_cards.append(str(chosen_card))
            dealer_suit.append(str(chosen_suit))

            dealer_sum += check_letters(chosen_card)
            card_print(chosen_suit, chosen_card)
            print('Dealer Total: ', dealer_sum)
            check_sum()
            hit_stay()



    def stay():
        global dealer_sum
        os.system('cls')
        print('-------------')
        print('STAY')
        #print('P Cards:', user_cards, user_suit)
        #print('D Cards:', dealer_cards, dealer_suit)

        # your hand
        print('-------------')
        print('Your Hand:')
        for i_index, card in enumerate(user_cards):
            card_print(user_suit[i_index], card)
        print('Your Total: ', user_sum)
        #print('Knock Function Executed')

        # dealer hand
        print('-------------')
        print('Dealer Hand: ')
        for i_index, card in enumerate(dealer_cards):
            card_print(dealer_suit[i_index], card)

        if dealer_sum >= 17:
            check_sum()
            hit_stay()
        elif dealer_sum < 17:
            time.sleep(1)
            chosen_card = random.choice(random_card)
            chosen_suit = random.choice(random_suit)

            dealer_cards.append(str(chosen_card))
            dealer_suit.append(str(chosen_suit))

            dealer_sum += check_letters(chosen_card)
            card_print(chosen_suit, chosen_card)
            print('Dealer Total: ', dealer_sum)
            check_sum()
            hit_stay()


    #outside of hit and knock function
    print('-------------')
    user_choice = str(input('Hit or Stay?(h/s): '))
    if user_choice == 'h':
        hit()
    elif user_choice == 's':
        stay()

def play_again():
    global dealer_sum
    global user_sum
    global dealer_cards
    global dealer_suit
    global turns
    global user_cards
    global user_suit
    global user_bet
    print(f'Balance: ${user_balance}')
    pG = str(input('Would you like to play again?(y/n): '))
    if pG == 'y':
        dealer_sum = 0
        user_sum = 0

        dealer_cards = []
        dealer_suit = []

        turns = 0

        user_cards = []
        user_suit = []

        user_bet = 0

        main()
    else:
        exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tTb2.png)
The cards are only printing under one another. I am a beginner in python. I started maybe 1 and a half weeks ago so please dont flame me for my code not being the most effiencent. Thanks

Comment: Consider yourself flamed for attaching a screenshot of textual data, see [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also, narrowing your problem to a [mre] will enhance reactions to your question. We don't really need to see all the game logic to answer the question.

Comment: You should store each line of your card drawing in 2D list and make a list of these 2D matrices. Once you have that, you can select multiple rows at a time and print them side by side. If you struggle with that, rephrase your question to something like "How to print 2D matrices of chars side-by-side?"

Comment: Pass the cards as a list to your function. Then print the top of each card in turn, then print the value of each card in turn, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the cards into an list and print them one line at a time:

```
def print_hand(hand):
    # Print first line of all cards in hand
    for card in hand:
        print("*------*", end=' ')
    print()
    # 2nd line
    for card in hand:
        print(f'| {card[0]:<2}   |', end=' ')
    print()
    # 3rd line
    for card in hand:
        print("|      |", end=' ')
    print()
    # 4th line
    for card in hand:
        print(f"|    {card[1]} |", end=' ')
    print()
    # Last line
    for card in hand:
        print("*------*", end=' ')

hand = [('A', '♥'), ('K', '♦'), ('4', '♣')]
print_hand(hand)
```

Output:

```
*------* *------* *------*  
| A    | | K    | | 4    | 
|      | |      | |      | 
|    ♥ | |    ♦ | |    ♣ | 
*------* *------* *------*
```

Comment: List, not array

Comment: @MatBailie go on and change it then.

Comment: I'm an old C programmer and often make the mistake of using "array" instead of "list". Also, the answer is a community wiki, so anyone with at least 100 rep can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to print cards in the same row:

```py
#import modules
from calendar import c
import random
import os
import time
from collections import namedtuple

#global variables
random_suit = ['♠','♥','♦','♣']
random_card = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
lettered_card = ['A', 'J', 'Q', 'K']

dealer_sum = 0
user_sum = 0

dealer_cards = []
dealer_suit = []

turns = 0

user_cards = []
user_suit = []

user_balance = og_balance = 1000.00
user_bet = 0

Card = namedtuple("Card", ["chosen_suit", "chosen_card"])
DEALER_CARD = ( f'*------*',
                f'| ???? |',
                f'| ???? |',
                f'| ???? |',
                f'*------*',
)
INDENT_SPACE = "   "

# Print cards
def card_print(*cards: Card):
    for c in cards:
        if c == DEALER_CARD:
            print(c[0], end="")
            continue
        print(f'*------*'+INDENT_SPACE, end="")
    print()
    for c in cards:
        if c == DEALER_CARD:
            print(c[1], end="")
            continue
        print(f'| {c.chosen_card:<2}   |'+INDENT_SPACE, end="")
    print()
    for c in cards:
        if c == DEALER_CARD:
            print(c[2], end="")
            continue
        print(f'|      |'+INDENT_SPACE, end="")
    print()
    for c in cards:
        if c == DEALER_CARD:
            print(c[3], end="")
            continue
        print(f'|    {c.chosen_suit} |'+INDENT_SPACE, end="")
    print()
    for c in cards:
        if c == DEALER_CARD:
            print(c[4])
            continue
        print(f'*------*'+INDENT_SPACE, end="")
    print()


#run
def main():
    os.system('cls')
    print('----------------------')
    print('Welcome to Blackjack!')
    bets()
    user_hand(2)
    time.sleep(1)
    dealer_hand()
    time.sleep(1)
    check_sum()
    hit_stay()

#bets
def bets():
    global user_bet
    global user_balance
    print(f'Your balance is currently: ${user_balance}')
    bet = int(input('How much would you like to bet?: $'))
    if bet < 0 or bet < 10:
        print('Minimum bet is $10')
        time.sleep(1)
        main()
    if bet > user_balance:
        print('Not enough money in balance')
        time.sleep(1)
        main()
    elif bet < user_balance:
        user_bet += bet
    else:
        print('Invalid Session.')
        time.sleep(1)
        main()

# Print dealer hand
def dealer_hand():
    global dealer_sum
    print('-------------')
    print('Dealer Hand: ')
    time.sleep(1)
    chosen_card = random.choice(random_card)
    chosen_suit = random.choice(random_suit)

    dealer_cards.append(str(chosen_card))
    dealer_suit.append(str(chosen_suit))

    dealer_sum += check_letters(chosen_card)
    card_print(Card(chosen_suit,chosen_card), DEALER_CARD)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Dealer Total: ', dealer_sum)

# Print user hand
def user_hand(amount):
    global user_sum
    print('-------------')
    print('Your Hand: ')
    cards_to_print = []
    for i in range(amount):
        time.sleep(1)
        chosen_card = random.choice(random_card)
        chosen_suit = random.choice(random_suit)

        user_cards.append(str(chosen_card))
        user_suit.append(str(chosen_suit))

        user_sum += check_letters(chosen_card)
        cards_to_print.append(Card(chosen_suit, chosen_card))
    card_print(*cards_to_print)
    print('Your Total: ', user_sum)

# Convert letters to numbers
def check_letters(chosen_card):
    if chosen_card.isdigit():
        return int(chosen_card)
    else:
        for _ in lettered_card:
            if chosen_card != 'A':
                return 10
            else:
                return 11

# Check if the total of the dealer or user is over 21
def check_sum():
    global user_bet
    global user_balance
    def win(bj):
        global user_bet
        global user_balance
        if bj:
            user_bet_won = user_bet * 1.75
            user_balance += user_bet_won
        else:
            user_bet_won = user_bet * 1.25
            user_balance += user_bet_won

    def lose():
        global user_bet
        global user_balance
        user_bet_lost = user_bet * 1.25
        user_balance -= user_bet_lost

    if user_sum > 21:
        print('-------------')
        print('Your over 21! You lose!')
        lose()
        play_again()
    elif dealer_sum > 21:
        print('-------------')
        print('Dealer over 21! You win!')
        win(False)
        play_again()
    elif user_sum == 21:
        print('-------------')
        print('You have Blackjack. You win!')
        win(True)
        play_again()
    elif dealer_sum == 21:
        print('-------------')
        print('Dealer has blackjack. You lose!')
        lose()
        play_again()
    elif dealer_sum > user_sum and turns > 0:
        print('-------------')
        print('Dealer has more. You lose!')
        lose()
        play_again()
    else:
        pass

# Hit or Knock
def hit_stay():
    global turns
    turns += 1
    def hit():
        global user_sum
        global dealer_sum
        os.system('cls')
        print('-------------')
        print('HIT')
        #print('P Cards:', user_cards, user_suit)
        #print('D Cards:', dealer_cards, dealer_suit)

        #your hand
        print('-------------')
        print('Your Hand: ')
        cards_to_print = []
        for i_index, card in enumerate(user_cards):
            cards_to_print.append(Card(user_suit[i_index], card))
        card_print(*cards_to_print)

        time.sleep(1)
        chosen_card = random.choice(random_card)
        chosen_suit = random.choice(random_suit)

        user_cards.append(str(chosen_card))
        user_suit.append(str(chosen_suit))

        user_sum += check_letters(chosen_card)
        card_print(Card(chosen_suit, chosen_card))
        print('Your Total: ', user_sum)

        # dealer hand
        print('-------------')
        print('Dealer Hand: ')
        cards_to_print = []
        for i_index, card in enumerate(dealer_cards):
            cards_to_print.append(Card(dealer_suit[i_index], card))
        card_print(*cards_to_print)

        if dealer_sum >= 17:
            check_sum()
            hit_stay()
        elif dealer_sum < 17:
            time.sleep(1)
            chosen_card = random.choice(random_card)
            chosen_suit = random.choice(random_suit)

            dealer_cards.append(str(chosen_card))
            dealer_suit.append(str(chosen_suit))

            dealer_sum += check_letters(chosen_card)
            card_print(Card(chosen_suit, chosen_card))
            print('Dealer Total: ', dealer_sum)
            check_sum()
            hit_stay()



    def stay():
        global dealer_sum
        os.system('cls')
        print('-------------')
        print('STAY')
        #print('P Cards:', user_cards, user_suit)
        #print('D Cards:', dealer_cards, dealer_suit)

        # your hand
        print('-------------')
        print('Your Hand:')
        cards_to_print = []
        for i_index, card in enumerate(user_cards):
            cards_to_print.append(Card(user_suit[i_index], card))
        card_print(*cards_to_print)
        print('Your Total: ', user_sum)
        #print('Knock Function Executed')

        # dealer hand
        print('-------------')
        print('Dealer Hand: ')
        cards_to_print = []
        for i_index, card in enumerate(dealer_cards):
            cards_to_print.append(Card(dealer_suit[i_index], card))
        card_print(*cards_to_print)
        

        if dealer_sum >= 17:
            check_sum()
            hit_stay()
        elif dealer_sum < 17:
            time.sleep(1)
            chosen_card = random.choice(random_card)
            chosen_suit = random.choice(random_suit)

            dealer_cards.append(str(chosen_card))
            dealer_suit.append(str(chosen_suit))

            dealer_sum += check_letters(chosen_card)
            card_print(Card(chosen_suit, chosen_card))
            print('Dealer Total: ', dealer_sum)
            check_sum()
            hit_stay()


    #outside of hit and knock function
    print('-------------')
    user_choice = str(input('Hit or Stay?(h/s): '))
    if user_choice == 'h':
        hit()
    elif user_choice == 's':
        stay()

def play_again():
    global dealer_sum
    global user_sum
    global dealer_cards
    global dealer_suit
    global turns
    global user_cards
    global user_suit
    global user_bet
    print(f'Balance: ${user_balance}')
    pG = str(input('Would you like to play again?(y/n): '))
    if pG == 'y':
        dealer_sum = 0
        user_sum = 0

        dealer_cards = []
        dealer_suit = []

        turns = 0

        user_cards = []
        user_suit = []

        user_bet = 0

        main()
    else:
        exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To make this possible, I used [collections.namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to order the cards data. This simplifies the access of the data in the `card_print` function and adds clarity to the code.

The `DEALER_CARD` constant has been added to print the card in the `card_print` function.